# cannot unselect checkbox element not visible

Tags: selenium, robotframework, selenium2library, robotframework-ide

I'm using robot framework selenium library, trying to unselect checkbox which is checked using
`unselect checkbox|id=blahblah` but I get element not visible exception.
But when I do `select checkbox|id=blahblah` it works. 
Should't it give element not visible consistently for unselect/select.
Any ideas how to fix this or work around?
I tried click element but same error

Comment: Try adding a wait before you `unselect` the check box? seems like youre trying to unslect it when its in the 3rd state (when the checkbox is highlighted but isnt a tick) if that makes sense

Comment: I tried `sleep|5` maybe I will try for longer time. But for select it's working i.e. doesn't get error element not visible. Shouldn't `select` also get same error?

Comment: It should - thats why i said i think its to do with the 3rd state. Maybe try a different locator? What is the whole error youre getting?

Comment: I put 60 sec wait but it's same error selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible

Answer (score 1):

try to do it by "click element" may be it run or cross check your locator.